# Ninject Injection Issues in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, singleton, ninject, ninject-2

I have three projects that will use DI.  My project is an ASP.NET MVC 3 site.  I installed the ninject MVC package from nuget which added my bootstrapper.   I registered my binding.

NinjectMVC3.cs

```
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
        }
```

I have a separate project that contains the UserService and IUserService.  In that project I also have a singleton factory class to create my services.

```
public class ServiceFactory : BaseFactory<ServiceFactory>
    {
        [Inject]
        public IUserService UserService { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there a reason why the above is always null when I call ServiceFactory.Instance.UserService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing: Most likely the factory isn't created by Ninject.

But as you shouldn't use the Singleton pattern anyway when doing Dependency Injection this should be easy to solve.

1. Pass `IUserService` to the constructor of any object that needs to know it.
2. Bind it as Singleton `kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>().InSingletonScope();`

Comment: Well I switched to doing this link http://www.shahnawazk.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html and still I am getting a null.  The kernel setup gets hit.  Also I maybe have multiple services on one controller and would hate to have 5 or 6 parameters inside that.  I would rather do property injection.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. That link does nowhere recommend to use the singleton pattern. Also, if you have to many dependencies on your constructor that is most likely not a problem of constructor injecion but rather that you do not follow the single responsibility principle correctly.

Comment: Furthermore I succest to use https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3 as MVC bootstrapper for Ninject

Comment: I figured it out by adding a constructor with IUserService as a parameter and it worked.  I will go with the direction of single responsibility principle.